# Summarize columns in R Data Frame independent of the order, (df$A,df$B) = (df$B,df$A)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, summarization

I have the following Data frame:

```
    
      destiny origin Count
    1 KJFK    SBBR       4
    2 KJFK    SAEZ    4683
    3 SBGL    KJFK       2
    4 SBBR    KJFK       2
    5 KJFK    SBGL    4987
    6 KJFK    SBGR   12911
    ...
```

As I'm interesting in the route, for me KJFK -> SBBR is the same as SBBR -> KJFK. So I want to sum their count, as the table below

```
    
      destiny origin Count
    1 KJFK    SBBR       6
    2 KJFK    SAEZ    4683
    3 SBGL    KJFK    4989
    4 KJFK    SBGR   12911
    ...
```

I did't want to use a big for loop to evaluate all the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(grp = paste0(sort(c(destiny, origin)), collapse = "_")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>%
    separate(grp, into = c("destiny", "origin"))
#        # A tibble: 4 x 3
#  destiny origin Count
#  <chr>   <chr>  <int>
#1 KJFK    SAEZ    4683
#2 KJFK    SBBR       6
#3 KJFK    SBGL    4989
#4 KJFK    SBGR   12911
```

Note that since you don't care about the order of `destiny`, `origin`, so here we order them alphabetically. So in the example you give above, `KJFK -> SBBR` and `SBBR -> KJFK` will become `destiny = KJFK, origin = SBBR`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  destiny origin Count
    1 KJFK    SBBR       4
    2 KJFK    SAEZ    4683
    3 SBGL    KJFK       2
    4 SBBR    KJFK       2
    5 KJFK    SBGL    4987
    6 KJFK    SBGR   12911", header =T)
```

Comment: It works fine :)
but mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) only format the second column, so I transform the first on into character before this

Comment: @gustavoPacheco The `mutate_if` works on all columns that are `factor` columns. Perhaps your first column was not a `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `pmin/pmax`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%       
  group_by(destinyN = pmin(destiny, origin), originN = pmax(destiny, origin)) %>% 
  summarise(destiny = first(destiny), 
            origin = first(origin), 
            Count = sum(Count)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-destinyN, -originN)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  destiny origin Count
#  <chr>   <chr>  <int>
#1 KJFK    SAEZ    4683
#2 KJFK    SBBR       6
#3 SBGL    KJFK    4989
#4 KJFK    SBGR   12911
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(destiny = c("KJFK", "KJFK", "SBGL", "SBBR", "KJFK", 
"KJFK"), origin = c("SBBR", "SAEZ", "KJFK", "KJFK", "SBGL", "SBGR"
), Count = c(4L, 4683L, 2L, 2L, 4987L, 12911L)), .Names = c("destiny", 
"origin", "Count"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
), class = "data.frame")
```