# Count combinations of categorical variables, regardless of order, in R?

Tags: r, combinations, categorical-data

Thanks for any help! I have a dataframe in R with two columns of categorical variables, like so:

```
rowA <- c("Square", "Circle", "Triangle", "Square", "Circle", "Triangle", "Square", "Circle", "Triangle")

rowB <- c("Circle", "Square", "Square", "Square", "Circle", "Circle", "Triangle", "Triangle", "Triangle")

df1 <- data.frame(rowA, rowB)

print(df1)
```

When we print it, it looks like this:

```
      rowA     rowB
1   Square   Circle
2   Circle   Square
3 Triangle   Square
4   Square   Square
5   Circle   Circle
6 Triangle   Circle
7   Square Triangle
8   Circle Triangle
9 Triangle Triangle
```

I want to count the frequency of each combination of categories in rowA and rowB. Here's what I'm hung up on -- the combinations are reversible, meaning "Square - Circle" is the same as "Circle - Square" for our purposes, and we want them to be summed together. The ideal output would look like this:

```
Pair             Count
Square - Circle      2
Square - Triangle    2
Square - Square      1
Circle - Triangle    2
Circle - Circle      1
Triangle - Triangle  1
```

I'd be thrilled if anybody had any advice, thanks!

Edit: Post got flagged as a duplicate question, but I don't agree that the suggested posts adequately answered my question (hence I asked in the first place, after a lot of digging). Really appreciate the unique and easy answers here.

Comment: [Pasting elements of two vectors alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588426/pasting-elements-of-two-vectors-alphabetically), and then count (e.g. [Count number of rows within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group)

Comment: A couple more related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15487151/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42144322/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51274241/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46536183/5325862

Comment: If you don't think the proposed duplicates answer your question you need to show us why they don't do that. Just saying you “don't agree” gives us nothing to go on even if you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could rearrrange by row with `pmin/pmax` and `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     count(Pair = str_c(pmin(rowA, rowB), ' - ',
       pmax(rowA, rowB)), name = "Count")
```

-output

```
             Pair   Count
1     Circle - Circle 1
2     Circle - Square 2
3   Circle - Triangle 2
4     Square - Square 1
5   Square - Triangle 2
6 Triangle - Triangle 1
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution is

```r
combs <- apply(as.matrix(df1), 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = " - "))
as.data.frame(table(combs))
#R>                 combs Freq
#R> 1     Circle - Circle    1
#R> 2     Circle - Square    2
#R> 3   Circle - Triangle    2
#R> 4     Square - Square    1
#R> 5   Square - Triangle    2
#R> 6 Triangle - Triangle    1

# in R 4.1.0 or later
as.matrix(df1) |> 
  apply(1, \(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = " - ")) |>
  table() |> as.data.frame() |> 
  setNames(c("Pair", "Count"))
#R>                  Pair Count
#R> 1     Circle - Circle     1
#R> 2     Circle - Square     2
#R> 3   Circle - Triangle     2
#R> 4     Square - Square     1
#R> 5   Square - Triangle     2
#R> 6 Triangle - Triangle     1
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach using a graph

```
library(igraph)
library(magrittr)
df1 %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  as_adjacency_matrix() 
#          Square Circle Triangle
# Square        1      2        2
# Circle        2      1        2
# Triangle      2      2        1
```