# How to speed up the computation of the intersections between each pair of sets for a large number of pairs

Tags: r, performance, intersection

I have the following dataframe:

```
> str(database)
'data.frame':   8547287 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ cited_id       : num  4.06e+08 5.41e+07 5.31e+07 5.04e+07 3.79e+08 ...
 $ cited_pub_year : num  2014 1989 2002 2002 2015 ...
 $ citing_id      : num  3.34e+08 3.37e+08 4.06e+08 4.19e+08 4.25e+08 ...
 $ citing_pub_year: num  2011 2011 2013 2014 2014 ...
```

The variables `cited_id` and `citing_id` contain the IDs of the objects from which this database has been obtained.

This is an example of the dataframe:

```
    cited_id cited_pub_year citing_id citing_pub_year
1  405821349           2014 419185055            2011
2  405821349           1989 336621202            2011
3   53148996           2002 406314162            2013
4   53148996           2002 419185055            2014
5  379369076           2015 424901495            2014
6   53148996           2011 441055669            2015
7  405821349           2014 447519383            2015
8  405821349           2015 469644221            2016
9  329268142           2014 470861263            2016
10  45433355           2008  55422577            2008
```

For example the ID 405821349 has been cited by 419185055, 336621202, 447519383 and 469644221. For each pair of IDs I would like to calculate the intersection of their citing IDs. The quantity `Pj.k` below is the length of the intersection. I tried with the following code

```
total_id<-c(database$cited_id,database$citing_id)
total_id<-unique(total_id)


df<-data.frame(data_k=character(),data_j=character(),Pj.k=numeric(),
               stringsAsFactors = F)
                            

for (k in 1:(length(total_id)-1)) {
  data_k<-total_id[k]
  citing_data_k<-database[database$cited_id==data_k,]
  
  for (j in (k+1):length(total_id)) {
    data_j<-total_id[j]
    citing_data_j<-database[database$cited_id==data_j,]
    Pj.k<-length(intersect(citing_data_j$citing_id,citing_data_k$citing_id))
    dfxx=data.frame(data_k=data_k,data_j=data_j,Pj.k=Pj.k,
                    stringsAsFactors = F)
    df<-rbind(df,dfxx)
  }
  
}
```

Anyway, it takes too long! How could I speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xtabs`, `tcrossprod` and sparse matrices:

```
library(Matrix)
library(data.table)

m2 <- as(
  triu(
    tcrossprod(
      m1 <- xtabs(data = database[,c(1, 3)], sparse = TRUE)
    ), k = 1
  ), "TsparseMatrix"
)

df <- data.frame(
  data_k = row.names(m1)[attr(m2, "i") + 1L],
  data_j = row.names(m1)[attr(m2, "j") + 1L],
  Pj.k = attr(m2, "x"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by answers in [Count combinations of categorical variables, regardless of order, in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260662/count-combinations-of-categorical-variables-regardless-of-order-in-r) , count pairs:

```r
database = read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = 
"cited_id cited_pub_year citing_id citing_pub_year
1  405821349           2014 419185055            2011
2  405821349           1989 336621202            2011
3   53148996           2002 406314162            2013
4   53148996           2002 419185055            2014
5  379369076           2015 424901495            2014
6   53148996           2011 441055669            2015
7  405821349           2014 447519383            2015
8  405821349           2015 469644221            2016
9  329268142           2014 470861263            2016
10  45433355           2008  55422577            2008")

database |>
  dplyr::count(pairs = paste(pmin(cited_id, citing_id), 
                             pmax(cited_id, citing_id)))
#>                  pairs n
#> 1  329268142 470861263 1
#> 2  336621202 405821349 1
#> 3  379369076 424901495 1
#> 4  405821349 419185055 1
#> 5  405821349 447519383 1
#> 6  405821349 469644221 1
#> 7    45433355 55422577 1
#> 8   53148996 406314162 1
#> 9   53148996 419185055 1
#> 10  53148996 441055669 1
```

Depending on what you actually need you might find `with(database, table(cited_id = cited_id, citing_id = citing_id))` useful too.